# Images on my server redirecing to Google?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

So I woke up this morning to my Wordpress websites all having their htaccess file modified (redirecting to spam). I replaced them with a backup file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And then I refreshed my site and only 5% of the images from my **/images/** folder are showing up.

All of my `<img src` paths are absolute. Even if I go to my image directory and click the image link directly, my browser thinks for a little bit and then goes to: **https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl**

However, like I said, about 5% of the image links **do** actually work, and they're all the same filetype in the same directory.

It's very strange.

**Edit: It seems to have been a server cache thing, things cleared up on their own after a few more minutes.**

Comment: Can you provide a website link?

Comment: Sounds like you're just interested in getting your site back on line, but patching a previously hacked install will in all likelihood leave you open to future/repeat attacks.  Might be worth taking a little longer and running through the advice in the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, this seemed to be a cache thing, it fixed itself. Though I do need to look more into the hack that occurred, I'm sure there's some underlying cause, the issue is I have multiple WP sites under my account and nearly all were affected, will be some fun to figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

First, clear the cache of your browser, or try with a "Private Session" of Chrome / Firefox, maybe redirects are just still in your cache.

Second, check if there is another .htaccess in the images directory or in any parent directory up to the root of your site and check its content.

Third, check if non working images are presents on filesystem.
If there aren't anymore the redirect come from Wordpress and not from Apache.

Your CMS has been defaced, if you have a backup I think it's a good idea to restore it, or at least compare it file by file with your actual site ([WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) can help you doing this).

I strongly suggest you to restore the backup and then check if your Wordpress installation is up-to-date and so every wordpress plugin you use.

Comment: Here's the [WordPress FAQ](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) on how to deal with a hacked site.